# Multiple List Comparison Assertion C#, Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm currently extracting text values from an error warning on a page, storing these values in a list using the `JavaScriptExecutor`.

Once these values are stored in a list, I have a serperate class with verification strings to compare the text values so I can assert these match.

I wrote an extension method to assist.

```
public bool CheckAlertDisplayWarnings()
{
  if (Modules.SpecificModule.AlertDisplay.Text.Contains("Error"))
  {
    var errorReturned =  Driver.ExecuteJavaScript<IReadOnlyCollection<object>>(JavaScriptStrings.ErrorMessageWarning);
    var validation = errorReturned.ToList();
    return validation.All(x => VerificationStrings.AllErrorWarnings.Contains(x));
  }
  return Modules.SpecificModule.AlertDisplay.Text.Contains(VerificationStrings.DealSuccessfullyCreated);
}
```

The problem I'm having is when comparing the list against the other list. Sometimes more than one error message is added to the `validation.ToList()`;

Can someone recommend an approach to iterate through each error warning in the Validation variable to match the other list values (all other error warnings are stored here) to return the `boolean value = true`?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what are you trying to achieve? I got it like you want to check that each validation message in `validation` is in `AllErrorWarning` and I can't see any problem

Comment: Hi Alexey, sorry I wasn't about the past couple of days. Verficationstring had multiple entries and the model returning the strings from the dev work had text errors meaning the strings were not matching. This is now resolved. Thanks for having a look.